# Index out of range problem

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following two for loops in sequence. It's very strange that the first for loop works when I run it alone. But when I run the second loop alone, I get a index out of range exception error. Can someone help me to check what the error is? Thanks a lot!

```
for (i = NiPricePointer; i < 551; i++)  
   {
      tempUpper = tempUpper + NiPriceCounter[i];
      if (tempUpper >= (NiPriceRounds * 0.3))
      {
          chart3.Series["Upper 30%"].Points.AddXY(k * 500, ((i - 1) * 0.1 + 5));
          break;
      }
 }

for (i = NiPricePointer; i>0; i--) //This loop always gives me out of range problems.
 {
      tempLower = tempLower + NiPriceCounter[i];
      if (tempLower >= (NiPriceRounds * 0.3))
      {
          chart3.Series["Lower 30%"].Points.AddXY(k * 500, ((i - 1) * 0.1 + 5));
          break;
       }
 }
```

The initialization of the array:

```
int[] NiPriceCounter = new int[551];
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you clarify the type and initial value of your `NiPricePointer`please?

Comment: NiPricePointer = Convert.ToInt32((Math.Round(System.Double.Parse(txbTotalCost2PerKgNi.Text), 1) - 5) * 10 + 1); //NiPriceCounter[NiPricePointer] points to the price which was input in first tab.

Comment: Does the exception occur on the line that reads `tempLower = tempLower + NiPriceCounter[i];`?

Comment: @Yunzhou: OK, so what is `NiPricePointer`'s value if you set a breakpoint before the first loop?

Comment: Did you just tried to check the value of i just before it raises the exception? (breakpoint?)

Comment: @Ynkzhou: What is the value of `i` when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose, NiPricePointer simply is greater than 550. Both of your loops should contain both bounds as a check:

```
for (i = NiPricePointer; i < 551 && i >=0; i++)
```

and

```
for (i = NiPricePointer; i < 551 && i >=0 ; i--)
```

Comment: I tried NiPricePointer -1 but unfortunately it still has the same problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Yunzhou: Than you have another problem. Please show us, where the exception occurs! I overlooked those breaks in your code, I updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: The exception occurs at tempLower = tempLower + NiPriceCounter[i];

Comment: @Yunzhou: Did you debug it and have a look at the value of i?

Comment: -1. `NiPricePointer` is not modified anywhere in the provided code. This looks to be a midpoint of some kind. The starting loop conditions are the same for both loops.

Comment: @Adam: Right you are. My answer - along with all others - is complete BS. I updated it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Adam Yes, that's why I'm confused. NiPricePointer is an integer value that I assigned.

Comment: @Yunzhou: Sorry for the confusion. I updated my answer - again.

Answer (score 0):

after first loop 
NiPricePointer will be increment by 1
so 
your second loop should be
`for(i = NiPricePointer-1;i>0;i--);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to each loop

```
Debug.Assert((i < 551) && (i >= 0));
```

Comment: It says The name 'Debug' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

> for (i = NiPricePointer; i>0; i--)

With this:

> for (i = 550; i>=0; i--)